# What is the meaning of "log" in "hours logged"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this [here](https://www.oxfordlearning.com/how-does-homework-affect-students/):

> The hours logged in class, and the hours logged on schoolwork can lead to students feeling overwhelmed and unmotivated.

What exactly the verbs "log in" or "log on" mean above? What they [mean](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/log) to me doesn't fit there.

Comment: See meaning number 2

Comment: @jmoreno No, it's meaning 1.1 under "Verb".

Comment: @200_success Indirectly, it's both. Essentially verb meaning 1.1 is the "every noun can be verbed" version of noun meaning 2.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To log your hours means to write them down in a log, usually at work, probably on such form:

[image: employee time sheet]

"Logging hours" in the context of your sentence would colloquially or metaphorically mean the hours spent in class and on doing schoolwork.

Comment: Possibly could be improved by clarifying that the "logging" in the quoted text is used in a metaphorical sense: no one is actually recording the time spent on these activities in a log.

Comment: That is what I meant by "colloquially"

Comment: Possibly the usage is influenced by the aviation world, where logging flight hours is mandatory and universal.

Answer (score 6):

'Log', verb, 2nd definiton, Merriam-Webster:

> to make a note or record of : enter details of or about in a log

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/log)

Comment: Except that no one is actually recording anything. At best its metaphorical, but more like an informal third definition.

Comment: @Andrew: except they possibly are.  It’s not at all unheard of for parents to require that their kids spend a set amount of time on home work and that this time be recorded.

Answer (score 3):

*Logged* here means *spent,* or *occupied,* even when the activity is not literally recorded in a journal or log.

In computer science, the verb phrases *log in* and *log on* mean *enroll,* or *provide credential.*

Answer (score 1):

***log*** is a noun and according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/log) is defined as:

> a record of performance, events, or day-to-day activities

So for example, *A teacher asks a student to record the time spent on different activities in a **log**book*.

***log*** can however also be a verb (the act of recording something either present or past tense) as follows:

- *The student is busy **logging** their time.* (present tense)
- *The student **logged** his time yesterday.* (past tense)